# Image doesn't insert in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to insert an image in HTML and I'm sure about the path but it wont show

```
<img src="C:\Users\96650\Downloads\A.JPG" alt="picture of angle" />
```

Comment: just a suggestion, save the image in same folder as your html file to avoid any such errors.

Comment: Save this image in folder where you got your website files and try relative path, not absolute

Comment: @Md.UsmanAnsari In windows path contains backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the image file into the same directory as your html file. If you already have a folder for your project, put the image file into it. If not, make a new folder on your computer and move both the html file and the image file into the folder. Then, the `src` value should be the name of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path properly and the extension of the file. Also, save the file in the same directory or one step below the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your image in the same folder to avoid any errors, but you can try this.

```
<img src="file:///C://Users\96650\Downloads\A.JPG" alt="picture of angle" />
```

It will work

Comment: Right click on the image and open it in any browser then copy link from the address bar ( try this if image is not in the same folder in which your html is loaded )

Answer (score 0):

you can't show image with specified path or out the partation in html you can only add image into the same folder or same partation.

1. example into folder: src="folder1/image.jpg".
2. example in same folder: src="image.jpg".
3. example out folder: src="../image.jpg".

Comment: i put them in the same folder and still the image cant load it shows me an icon like X

Comment: ok if your imageName is A.jpg.....................                copy this script:    <img src="A.JPG" alt="picture of angle" />  and reply me